# Is it possible to run Unity3D Tests inside of Rider?

Tags: unity-game-engine, nunit, jetbrains-ide, rider

Is it possible to run the Unity3d Tests inside of Rider? Rider detects those tests but the result is "Inconclusive, Test not run".

The Unity3D plugin is installed.

Comment: I think you'd better ask for support from Rider instead.

Comment: Yeah, but I have seen questions related to this without a solution and hoped someone was simply able to do it. I am pretty sure there must be a lot of people having tried this and SO seemed the best way to reach them :)

Comment: Unity version, OS and type of test (does it use GameObject) all of this matters.

Comment: Tests with GameObject can be run in Unity Editor only.

Comment: If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is no because the assemblies have a dependency on Unity native code (not .NET) which makes tests depend on the whole engine (more at [Unity support plugin for ReSharper bug](https://github.com/JetBrains/resharper-unity/issues/96)).

There's even a more serious issue for ReSharper that [fails on running pure NUnit tests](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-6711)

Comment: NUnit tests execution has just been fixed in 2017.3 !!

Comment: And now its possible to run Unity3d tests inside Rider from 2018.1 onwards